# Get client connections on cifs share from command line equal to Computer Management view

Tags: powershell, batch-file, connection, nas

I would like to use either command line or Powershell to gather the number of client connections on different shares from our NAS'es, multiple vendors.
Connecting *"Computer Management"* to a NAS-device, this gives us a nice overview of the connections per share under *System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Shares*. Is it possible to get the same information using `cmd` or `powershell` script?

[image: Computer Management View]

Comment: PowerShell: `Get-SmbShare|Format-Table Name,CurrentUsers`.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-SmbShare`, as mentioned by PetSerAl, can list file shares on Windows machines([Windows 8/Server 2012 and later](https://serverfault.com/questions/436843/how-to-use-new-smbshare-with-powershell-3-0-on-windows-7)). I do not know if it can enumerate shares on other vendor products that are visible as SMB shares to a Windows machine.

```
Get-SmbShare | Select Name,ScopeName,PathName,CurrentUsers
```

For NetApp products, the [DataONTAP PowerShell Toolkit](http://community.netapp.com/t5/Microsoft-Cloud-and-Virtualization-Discussions/NetApp-PowerShell-Toolkit-4-0-containing-DataONTAP-PowerShell-Toolkit-3-3/m-p/109322) has scripts for managing shares, but I'm not sure of the specific commands you would need for the desired output.

For Windows 7/Server 2008 R2, [this article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/managing-file-shares-windows-powershell) discusses a way to use WMI directly to query file shares.

For other products, you may want to contact their respective support teams.